# Basic properties of the support of functions. What am I considering wrong?

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

If $f,g:\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R, \lambda \in \Bbb R^*, \xi\in \Bbb R^n$ then prove that:

- supp($f+g$) $\subset$ supp($f$) $\cup$ supp($g$)

  > I get why "$\supset$" doesn't happen, and my counterexample is: $f(x)=x, g(x)=-x$, however while looking for counterexamples, I found these functions: $f(x)=x, g(x)=x+1$ where supp($f$)=$\Bbb R-\{0\}$, supp($g$)=$\Bbb R-\{-1\}$ and supp$(f+g)$=$\Bbb R-\{-\frac 12\}$, in this case "$\subset$" doesn't follow, am I adding wrong? or maybe I'm not understanding the definition of support, what's wrong?
- supp($T_{\xi}f$)=$\xi+supp(f)$

This one looks very simple, however writing it confuses me. Here $T_{\xi}f(x):=f(x-\xi)$.

 We know that for each $x_0\in \text{Dom}(f)=\Bbb R^n$ corresponds a unique $y_0=x_0-\xi\in \text{Dom}(T_{\xi}f)=\Bbb R^n$, so in particular, for the elements of the support, the same happens, so if $y\in supp(T_{\xi}f)$ then $y=x-\xi$ with $x\in supp(f)$, then supp($T_{\xi}f$)=$\{x-\xi:x\in supp(f)\}$, wich looks similar to what we wanted, but I'm not sure if I'm right.

Comment: In the first example, $\operatorname{supp}(f) \cup \operatorname{supp}(g) = \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @T.Bongers Oh God! that's true!!! I'm so sorry (and so silly)...